# pyautogui.keyDown and pyautogui.keyUp not working on Mac with Python

Tags: python, keypress, pyautogui

Based on some events using object detection, I'm trying to press Up and Down keys, but that's not working on Python.

Env: Python3 and macOS Catalina 10.15.5

The conditions are fulfilled to press the keys as I'm printing it as shown:

```
if(x>0 and y<160):
        print("up")
        pyautogui.keyDown('up')
        pyautogui.keyUp('up')
elif(x>0 and y>320):
        print("down")
        pyautogui.keyDown('down')
        pyautogui.keyUp('down')
```

The way I'm using this code is to press keys based on object movement detected by Camera. The object detection and the conditions are working well because I can see the printed output. To test the results of keypress, I'm running a browser window game to test if it works. Alternatively, I also opened a code editor to check if the keypress moves the cursor, but no luck.

I ran the python file from the terminal with and without sudo command and ensured it is not a permission issue. Also, I ensured that the game window or the editor was focused (active window) while testing.

I also tried using pyautogui.press('up') instead of key down and key up but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Try adding a ```time.sleep(0.1)``` between keyDown and keyUp. (You also need to ```import time```)

Comment: @Andrej I tried that. Went upto 1 sec delay, but still no luck. (I imported time)

Comment: Similar issue here on Windows.